# Подключение css и javascript к сайту

Tags: html, javascript, css

Обычно css и javascript подключаются так

```
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Nexus</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/global.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/load.css">
 <script src="javascript/librarie.js"></script>
 <script src="javascript/load.js"></script>
 <script src="javascript/req.js"></script>
</head>
```

но возможно ли их подключать в любом другом теге ?

например внутри `<body>` в `<div>` :

```
<div id='head'>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/global.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/load.css">
 <script src="javascript/librarie.js"></script>
 <script src="javascript/load.js"></script>
 <script src="javascript/req.js"></script>
</div>
```

Если это возможно то в каком теге лучше это делать и вообще могут ли быть проблемы с таким подключением?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript работает с DOM моделью документа html, модель DOM формируется пока не загрузится весь html, Вы можете подключать JS в любом месте, но это не рекомендуется, а если на то пошло, то подключать нужно перед закрывающим тегом body. То есть после всего содержимого, так как оно должно загрузится, чтобы сформировать DOM модель.

UPD: Забыл про стили.

Стили можно подключать только в теге head. Так, как это определено в спецификации.

Comment: а если мне необходимо по мере работы сайта (без перезагрузки страницы) убирать и добавлять стили и javascript библиотеки к сайту как это возможно заделать  чтобы пользователь ничего не заметил ?

Comment: Лучше опишите Вашу задачу. Изначально что-то не то в Ваших планах =)

Comment: делаю сайт по типу десктопа и там накапливается дафига стилей и и библиотек и мне пришла в голову идея убирать не нужные стили и библиотеки это плохо ?

Comment: Это отлично! Используйте условия (if,else,switch) для вывода нужных стилей и библиотек в зависимости от страницы. =)

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/questions/179968/javascript-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7-head-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8

Comment: Мне кажется стоит посмотреть в сторону YUI loader. Или полностью перейти на YUI. Я кстати тоже планирую заняться чем-то подобным. Если хотите могу поделиться идеями.